# Automatically accept non-conflicting "their" changes on interactive rebase

Tags: git

Suppose I have a small "feature" branch that is based on a previous working release commit. I am introducing some necessary though limited changes to a set of files. When a time comes to merge a Pull Request I may have to merge the latest changes from the master first in order to resolve conflicts:
`MyCommit -> MergeMasterCommit` - this is the history for my feature branch.
During a code review some modifications to my changes have to be made. Since I am doing my commits as atomic and coherent as possible, I want to modify a commit before a merge commit (`MyCommit`).
When I go to interactive rebase and modify `MyCommit` I am faced with an impossible task to "resolve" each and every commit that has been introduced by `MergeMasterCommit` (there may be tens of them). Clearly, I am not interested in resolving any files that were affected by `MyCommit`.

So, is it possible to automatically accept "their" changes for every file except those modified by `MyCommit` (in case there may be conflicts)?

Comment: This kind of thing is probably best done *without* endless rebasing. You can abuse `-X ours` (remembering that the ours/theirs notions are squirrelly during rebasing) but this will blindly choose the wrong chunks of code for some cases. Using merge instead of rebase will give you a much more controllable and workable experience.

Comment: @torek this is what I ended up doing: I reseted a local branch to a commit before the "final" merge, modified my commit history with necessary changes and then merged the latest changes from the upstream. After that I force pushed, rewriting my feature branch before it is merged into master...